# python error: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0,69

Tags: python, csv, floating-point, jupyter

"I have to change the format of a object list ['Dev'] to float64, but python send me this error. 'Dev'its a column of objects from a csv table ('prueba.csv') and I need to translate it for create statistics/metrics, could you help me?"

#start the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

#read the data from .csv file;

```
df = pd.read_csv('prueba.csv', sep=';', decimal=',',encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

#Data description

```
df.dtypes

Element      object
Property     object
Nominal     float64
Actual       object
Tol -       float64
Tol +       float64
Dev          object
Check       float64
Out         float64
dtype: object
```

#List for float translate;

```
df['Dev']
0        0,69
1        0,62
2        0,54
3        0,47
4        0,19
5       -0,26
6        0,11
7         0,1
8         0,2
9        0,29
10      -1,54
11         -2
12      -2,06
13      -2,02
14      -2,08
15      -1,39
16      -1,68
17      -1,91
18      -1,78
19       -1,8
20      -1,21
21      -1,07
22      -0,97
23      -1,47
24      -1,35
25      -0,91
26      -1,17
27      -0,67
28      -1,12
29      -1,13
1962        0
1963    -0,37
1964     0,02
1965     0,32
1966     0,04
1967        0
1968     0,39
1969     0,25
1970     0,38
1971     0,15
1972        0
1973     1,11
1974    -1,13
1975     0,15
1976     0,12
1977        0
1978    -0,47
1979    -0,85
1980     0,08
1981     0,23
1982        0
1983     1,03
1984    -0,76
1985    -0,03
1986     0,02
1987        0
1988     0,36
1989    -1,45
1990     0,12
1991     0,09
Name: Dev, Length: 1992, dtype: object
```

#Function definition for conversion

```
def convert_currency(val):
    """
     - Remove commas and u'
     - Convert to float type
    """
    new_val = val.replace("u'","'")
    return float(new_val)

df['Dev'].apply(convert_currency)
```

#Python error;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-9ac4450806f7> in <module>()
----> 1 df['Dev'].apply(convert_currency)

C:\Users\kaosb\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3589             else:
   3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3592 
   3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-89-0c43557e37eb> in convert_currency(val)
      5     """
      6     new_val = val.replace("u'","'")
----> 7     return float(new_val)

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0,69
```

Comment: Its likely that pandas is unable to recognize that the encoding is "Western European" format. Can you try again with `encoding=latin_1` (its just another alias for Western-european encoding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are not replacing the commas

```
def convert_currency(val):
    """
     - Remove commas and u'
     - Convert to float type
    """
    new_val = val.replace("u'","").replace(",",".")
    return float(new_val)
```

would do the trick.

your floats need dot instead of comma like you said.

Comment: I tried but...;   ValueError: could not convert string to float: ???

Comment: that means it's time to debug. 
clause the float(new_val) function with try and except, and if it threw error, print it and give a default value.
this way you can see why thats not working. my guess is you have some weird characters which are failing the function

Comment: Thanks Hagai Kalinhoff

Comment: no problem friend!
please mark this answer as 'accepted' so other may view it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the commas by points before applying float otherwise the float function considers you're giving to arguments

Answer (score 0):

Just change your encoding to `latin_1`.
I tried locally and it works great, it automatically assigns its dtype as float64.

Comment: How do you change the encoding? maybe like this? df = pd.read_csv('prueba.csv', sep=';', decimal=',',encoding='latin_1 ') Thanks!!